# spotfire how to get the last value in a column?

Tags: spotfire

I have a data table as below. I would like to get the last `[Action]` of each `[Sstage]` of each `[ID]` based on the `[Time]`.

I tried: `last(action)over intersect([id],[stage],[time])` but it is not giving me what I want. does anyone have any idea?

```
+----+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| ID |  Stage  |     Action      |    Time    |   Last_Action   |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | CEO     | Decline         | 11/01/2016 | requestmoreinfo |
|  1 | CEO     | Approve         | 11/02/2016 | requestmoreinfo |
|  1 | CEO     | Approve         | 11/03/2016 | requestmoreinfo |
|  1 | CEO     | requestmoreinfo | 11/04/2016 | requestmoreinfo |
|  1 | Manager | requestmoreinfo | 11/05/2016 | Decline         |
|  1 | Manager | requestmoreinfo | 11/06/2016 | Decline         |
|  1 | Manager | Approve         | 11/07/2016 | Decline         |
|  1 | Manager | Decline         | 11/08/2016 | Decline         |
|  2 | User    | Decline         | 11/09/2016 | Approve         |
|  2 | User    | Decline         | 11/10/2016 | Approve         |
|  2 | User    | Approve         | 11/11/2016 | Approve         |
+----+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one probably isn't as obvious as most.

We have to find out what the status is for the `Max([Time])` over the `[ID]` and `[Stage]`. You are close using `Last()` but that method is to get the logical last row. If your data isn't sorted... then this would give undesired results. Thus, use the `Max()` method to get the most recent date.

```
Max([Time]) OVER (Intersect([ID],[Stage]))
```

Now... this would put the `[Time]` in your calculated column... since you want the correlated `[Action]`, we need to nest that in an `IF()` statement to find the `[Action]`

```
If([Time]=Max([Time]) OVER (Intersect([ID],[Stage])),[Action])
```

Now, this would put the correct `[Action]` in your calculated column, but only on the row containing the `Max([Time])`.

The last step is to apply this value across your `[ID],[Stage]` grouping with one more `Over()` method

```
First(If([Time]=Max([Time]) OVER (Intersect([ID],[Stage])),[Action])) OVER (Intersect([ID],[Stage]))
```